# MySQL index on numerical columns makes query slower

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I have an optimisation problem with a fairly large table (~1.7M rows).

There are two columns used when selecting rows, let's call them colA and colB. They are both of type 'double' (5 decimal places) and range from:

colA: -90 ~ 90
colB: -180 ~ 180

Without an index, any query of the form:

```
SELECT * FROM table where colA BETWEEEN a and b AND colB BETWEEN c and d
```

takes approximately the same time to run (~ 1 second), regardless of the range of (a,b), and (c,d) (as MySQL has to examine every row).

If I add an index to colA and colB, two things happen: queries where the (a,b) & (c,d) range are small, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM table where colA BETWEEEN -4 and 4 AND colB BETWEEN 3 and 7
```

run very quickly (~ 1/10 second). However, the execution time increases with the range between the queried values. For example:

```
 SELECT * FROM table where colA BETWEEEN -80 and 80 AND colB BETWEEN -150 and 150
```

takes about a minute to execute.

I know how B-trees works for strings, but I'm not sure of the mechanism when the data is numeric and the query is conducted using a range.

If anyone could suggest how to optimise this query I would be grateful. One thought is to use the index for small ranges and tell MySQL not to use it for larger ones, however I couldn't find a command which allows this.

Thanks

EDIT: the explains

There is something I stupidly forgot to mention. The results are ordered by rand() - I'm aware of how inefficient this is, but I could see no other way to get a limited number of rows from the table randomly.

Adding rand() does not affect the execution time when there is no index, but drastically increases the time taken when there is.

EDIT2: this is using composite indexes.

**SMALL RANGE:**

"explain select * from table where colA between 35 and 38 and colB between -10 and 5 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20"

9783 rows

NO INDEX (fast)

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1673784 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

WITH INDEX (very fast)

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | range | test          | test | 18      | NULL | 136222 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

**LARGE RANGE:**

"explain select * from table where colA between -80 and 80 and colB between -150 and 150 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20;"

1631862 rows

NO INDEX (fast)

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1673784 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

WITH INDEX (very slow: > 60 seconds)

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | ALL  | test          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1673784 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

**EDIT3:**

To summarize:(all queries limited to return 20 rows)

big range with rand() with index: **45 seconds** 
big range without rand(), with index: 0.003 seconds 

big range with rand, no index: 1 second
big range without rand, no index: 0.003 seconds

The anomaly is: "big range with rand() with index, 45 seconds".

Comment: Put `EXPLAIN` for both queries please. Also you'll see yourself that in second case no index is used

Comment: "If I add an index to colA and colB" --- clarify this please. For the queries you showed us - the most efficient would be to create 2 **separated** indexes. One for `ColA`, and another for `ColB`.

Comment: @zerkms: Why would two separated indexes be more efficient than a composite index? In the queries shown, both columns are present in the where clause, combined with AND, which seems to be the perfect scenario for a composite index.

Comment: @zerkms, incorrect. two separated indexes is not good, too many duplicates.

Comment: @Thilo: just because `BETWEEN` (as well as `<`, etc) cannot be optimized for being used for both key parts. Read about `index range`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-multi-part

Comment: @user247245: your phrase that I was incorrect is incorrect ;-P

Comment: I'll get the EXPLAINS, gotta recreate the indexes

Comment: "Adding rand() does not affect the execution time when there is no index, but drastically increases the time taken when there is." Does removing rand() decrease the time taken when there is an index (and a big range)?

Comment: big range with rand() with index: 45 seconds ** 
big range without rand(), with index: 0.003 seconds **
**************
big range with rand, no index: 1 second **
big range without rand, no index: 0.003 seconds

Comment: "big range without rand(), with index: 0.003 seconds" Can you verify that this is still using the index?

Comment: Sorry for the formatting above. It seems that adding rand() increases the time drastically when there is an index (from 0.003 to 45 seconds) but not so when there is no index (from 0.003 to 1 second)

Comment: @thilo let me see, it might have cached that just now. edit: It is using the index. All queries are using 'LIMIT 20'

Comment: Just realised it wouldn't cache the queries as they are ordered with rand()

Comment: I think the LIMIT 20 makes the difference. See my updated answer. As for solutions, probably just drop the index, or add a hint for when the range is large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know how B-trees works for strings, but I'm not sure of the mechanism when the data is numeric and the query is conducted using a range.

They work the same way for numbers as they do for strings.

> Without the index the query takes approximately the same time to run (~ 1 second), regardless of the range of (a,b), and (c,d)

The runtime of a full table scan does not significantly vary with the contents of the WHERE condition. The time taken by the index access path is proportional to the number of rows returned. If a query selects a significant part of the table, using an index will always be slower than not using an index.

An index access path is only efficient if the index selectivity is sufficient, i.e. the number of rows retrieved is small (some say 10% at the very most). Execution time will be roughly proportional to the number of rows returned, and could end up slower than a full table scan.

> One thought is to use the index for small ranges and tell MySQL not to use it for larger ones, however I couldn't find a command which allows this.

The query optimizer has to use statistics and heuristics to determine if an index should be used. Maybe you need to update these statistics using [OPTIMIZE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html). If it still fails to make the proper decision, you can help it with [hints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html).

```
SELECT * FROM table 
   IGNORE INDEX (the_index)
   where colA BETWEEEN -80 and 80 AND colB BETWEEN -150 and 150
```

Other options could be deleting the index (if you never see any benefit from it, a constant one second response time might be good enough), or trying a composite index on both columns (also only if the number of records resulting from the query is small).

---

Now that you mention LIMIT 20, it starts making more sense:

> big range with rand() with index: 45 seconds

NESTED LOOP with many results + SORT

Get ALL the records (in the range) from the index, fetch them one by one from the table, then sort, then limit to 20

> big range without rand(), with index: 0.003 seconds

NESTED LOOP aborted at 20 records

Get 20 records from the index, fetch them one by one from the table, and return them. No sorting, in effect no big range.

> big range with rand, no index: 1 second

FULL TABLE SCAN + SORT

Read through the whole table, keep what is in range, then sort, then limit to 20

> big range without rand, no index: 0.003 seconds

FULL TABLE SCAN, aborted at 20 records

Start reading through the table, keep what is in range, stop when you have 20 and return.

Comment: I prefer to avoid the advices about weird (yes, this practice is terrible) `IGNORE INDEX` before OP shows us `EXPLAINS`. And in explains we'll see, that mysql already ignores the indexes itself, I bet.

Comment: Agree that we should look at EXPLAINS first. But if the query is much slower now than before he created the indexes, mysql is probably not ignoring the indexes...

Comment: @Thilo: we don't know what values were in `a` and `b` before ;-) he did not say that.

Comment: "Without the index the query takes approximately the same time to run (~ 1 second), regardless of the range of (a,b), and (c,d) "

Comment: @Thilo: i can't believe that query with **any** values will behave the same. Anyway, let's wait explains.

Comment: The runtime of a full table scan does not significantly vary with the contents of the WHERE condition. The time taken by the index access path is proportional to the number of rows returned. If a query selects a significant part of the table, using an index will always be slower than not using an index.

Comment: @Thilo: if index scan takes about a minute - then he has a really "huge amount of data". Fullscan over "huge amount of data" cannot be run in one second ;-) I bet he just experienced the mysql cache results.

Comment: The index scan does not take a minute. Picking the thousands of returned rows one by one using random access out of the table is what is taking the time. Good point about the cache though. That could distort results quite a bit. However, it seems that OP is seeing this issue consistently.

Comment: @Thilo: btw, what about separated indexes? ;-)

Comment: "Picking the thousands of returned rows one by one using random access out of the table is what is taking the time" --- yep, silly me, missed that.

Comment: I am thinking he has separated indexes now. We need him to clarify that. I believe a composite index could mitigate the problem, but essentially the problem remains (selectivity too low). If, as you say, MySQL does not support range scans on composite indexes (which I cannot really believe, but I'm an Oracle guy, so what do I know), then of course, this is not even an option.

Comment: @Thilo: even for oracle it will be better to use 2 separated indexes, because of oracle can do intelligent index merges. But I'm not 100% sure in this, since I haven't enough experience with it.

Comment: With Oracle, a composite index would definitely be better. An index merge is kind of a fall-back technique when the "proper" index is missing. In a situation where each index and the end result have very poor selectivity, an index merge would be even worse than using just one of the two indexes alone. Maybe this is what is happening here actually. Still waiting for the explain.

Comment: The results did not differ (subjectively) when I tried separate indexes (as opposed to composite).

Comment: @Thilo: what do you think now? Imho the behaviour is very strange :-S

Comment: The question is a little confusing now but the main point is this: the query with indexes performs much faster (as expected) except when 'order by rand()' is present. With rand(), the indexed query is, at worst, about 60 times slower than the same, unindexed query.

Comment: Without "order by rand()", you still have "limit 20", right? With limit 20 (and no sorting), the index query will be relatively constant (regardless of range, because the range is effectively capped at 20). With sorting it has to get the records from the complete range, and then sort all of them, regardless of limit. If you remove the limit 20 (with index), you should see performance degrade in a way similar to the order by version.

Comment: Thanks - your explanation makes sense. It seems there is no way to really optimise this query - it's unfortunate that there isn't a better way to pick out random rows.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes with many duplicates are a waste.

Make sure your index uses both fields;

```
create index idx_faster on tbl_mytbl (colA,colB)
```

for colB you may add another,

```
create index idx_colb on tbl_mytbl (colB)
```

regards,
/t

Answer (score 0):

Last query should not take longer than first. MySQL may not have the index updated see [`OPTIMIZE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/optimize-table.html)

Also you can check how it is planning the query with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Finally, you can force the index to be disabled with [`IGNORE INDEX (idx_name)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html)